# Preferred foreach Index Type

Tags: foreach, d

What is the preferred type for loop indexes when using `foreach` in D, `int`, `uint` or simply automatic by omitting the type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, indices should be `size_t`. The same with `length`. You're going to have issues with 32-bit vs 64-bit machines if you try and use `int` or `uint`. `size_t` is what the language uses for array indices and `length`. It's aliased to `uint` on 32-bit machines and `ulong` on 64-bit machines.

So, if you're going to give an index a type, give it `size_t`. However, the type will be inferred to be `size_t` by `foreach` when iterating over an array. So, in most cases, there's no reason to list the type.

Comment: Just like in C++ then. From what I have seen in algorithms on github there's a big sloppyness in choosing this type with care. Most use `int` or `uint`. Thx.